# Basic question about how to call a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rubygems

I really should know this... but I don't. Here's is a method provided in the documentation for a gem, [Barby](http://barby.rubyforge.org/rdoc/):

```
valid?()
```

And here is a functioning callback in my model:

```
  require 'barby'
  require 'barby/barcode/bookland'

def barcode

  if Barcodeimg.find_by_isbn_id(self.id).nil?
     barcode = Barby::Bookland.new("'#{self.productidentifier_idvalue}'")
     my_bc = Barcodeimg.new(:client_id => self.client_id, :isbn_id => self.id) 
     f = File.open("barcode.png", 'w+')
     f.write barcode.to_png
     my_bc.image = f
     my_bc.save!
  end
end
```

However, sometimes I get a 'data not valid' error, so I'd like, obviously, to use the valid? method. But I don't know how to call it. If I do

```
  if self.productidentifier_idvalue.valid?
```

I get

```
undefined method `valid?' for "9781551113180":String
```

Edit: more errors:

If I do

```
barcode = Barby::Bookland.new("'#{self.productidentifier_idvalue}'")
if barcode.valid?
#more
```

I get the Barby error 'data not valid'

Comment: Are you sure your isbn id is always valid? The `data not valid error` could come from that.

Comment: The id is, as it's a primary key integer created by the app. I've been deliberately giving it an invalid ISBN13 (productidentifier_idvalue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're giving an invalid ISBN here

```
barcode = Barby::Bookland.new("'#{self.productidentifier_idvalue}'")
```

it's no wonder it gives you the `data not valid` error. Check the value of `self.productidentifier_idvalue` and make sure it's 12 digits (the regexp to validate the code can be seen [here](https://github.com/toretore/barby/blob/master/lib/barby/barcode/ean_13.rb#L53)).

**Update**

Replace `"'#{self.productidentifier_idvalue}'"` with `self.productidentifier_idvalue`. The way you're doing it, the result of your expression is `'123456789012'`, which is two quotes too many.

Besides, you don't really need to call `valid?`, it's done in the initializer as you can see [here](https://github.com/toretore/barby/blob/master/lib/barby/barcode/bookland.rb#L15).

Comment: Great. I've used a regex: if /^(97(8|9))?\d{9}(\d|X)$/.match(self.productidentifier_idvalue) , then continued to create the barcode once we know the ISBN's valid. Thanks for your patience with me!

Comment: No problem. Note that you can also use `if self.productidentifier_idvalue =~ /^(97(8|9))?\d{9}(\d|X)$/`, which is a bit more idiomatic (although it all boils down to taste I guess ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception, you're calling this on a string, which doesn't know that method. You need to call it on wherever your Barby::Barcode instance is.

According to the documentation "Bookland" is a special case of "pure" EAN-13 data.

So, maybe doing something like

```
bc = Barby::EAN13.new(productidentifier_idvalue)
bc.valid?
```

Should get you closer to your aim

Comment: How funny, I just tried that as you posted, see q edit. It's throwing a 'data not valid' error (which is why I tried interpolating the number). Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

The valid? method exists only on objects which are instances of the [Barcode class](http://barby.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Barby/Barcode.html)

You're calling this method on a String.

Comment: Oh yes, duh. Can you see my question edit to see why this next attempt doesn't work? Ta!